# Problema con el for de JavaScript y una vista de usuario

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con el blucle for de JavaScript y es que no estoy logrando que pasarle los valores a mi vista de usuario. El programa guarda los datos que le paso pero no ejecuta la instrucción del bucle for y mucho menos la muestra en la vista del navegador.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <title>For algorithm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey">
        <h2>For algorithm demo</h2>
        <p>A for in programming is used when we want to repeat a set of instructions a finite number of times</p>
        <p>Try it...</p>
    
        <p><label>Introduce a number</label>
            <div id="number">
                <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="input" type="text">
            </div>
        </p>
        <div>
            <p><button class="w3-button w3-green">Let's go!</button></p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var n;

n = document.getElementById("number");

for (var i = 0; i < n;  i = i + 1){

  number.innerHTML += `<h1>Your count is: ${number}</h1>`;

}
```

Comment: Hola, comparte si la consola de desarrollo te arroja un error, esto nos puede ayudar a ayudarte

Comment: ¿Tu código es tal cual lo has puesto? No puedes tener código Javascript fuera de una etiqueta `<script>` (y fuera de `<html>`) y esperar que funcione

Comment: Algo asi necesitas? https://jsfiddle.net/dj7s0xpy/2/

Comment: Tienes multitud de problemas: no tienes etiqueta <script>, usas la variable n como si su valor fuera un entero, pero es un elemento del DOM, usas la variable number sin haberla definido... Quizá debas estudiar un poco más, deberías ser capaz de evitar estos errores sin esfuerzo.

Comment: Todavia no estoy muy familiarizado con el formato de publicacion de stack overflow, pero en mi local evidentemente tengo el archivo de scripts correspondiente linkeado al HTML, disculpen esa confusión

Answer (score 0):

> Tenes un editor de código para poder subir tus consultas Con la lógica
> que usas .Contesto porque veo que aun corrigiendo varios errores no mostraría en la pagina lo
> que se pretende porque en cada bucle mostraría y desaparecería la
> inserción y me resulto interesante

```js
function agregar(x) {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
  x.innerHTML = ""

  for (let i = 1; i <= inputValue; i = i + 1) {
    var agrega = 'insertar'
    var uno = `${agrega}..  ${i}..veces.. `

    x.innerHTML += uno

  }

}
```

```html
<h2>For algorithm demo</h2>
<p>A for in programming is used when we want to repeat a set of instructions a finite number of times</p>
<p>Try it...</p>

<p>
  <label>Introduce a number</label>
  <div id="number">
    <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="input" type="text" id="input">
  </div>
</p>
<div onclick="agregar(this)">
  <p><button>Let's go!</button></p>
</div>
```